# flutter web has white space in new iphone 13

Tags: iphone, flutter, dart

[image]

I have a Flutter web app with Flutter SDK version 3.7.10 (stable) but in new iPhones (iPhone 13, ios version 16.4) mobile browsers it doesn't show the fullscreen and has white space.

I have the updated stable branch, and cleaned the cache and project but I couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

try to check it on different device, it could be a "width" issue, did you try to expand the widget or check the given width.
ALso you can use Flutter UI DevTools on web (after you enable mobile view)

[image]

[image]